# Probability distribution $P_X$ of $F_X(z)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\lfloor z\rfloor}\dfrac{1}{2^k}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm looking for the probability distribution $P_X$ of $F_X(z)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\lfloor z\rfloor}\dfrac{1}{2^k}$.

We define $\lfloor z\rfloor:=\text{sup}(\{n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}|n\leq z\})$ and note that sup$(\varnothing)=-\infty$.

Just looking at it I'd say that inorder to calculate $P(a<X\leq b)$ you would just subtract $F_X(b)-F_X(a)$ and be done. That makes for a rather ugly expression however. Is there a nicer expression obtainable ?

Comment: $F_X$ is the probability distribution.  The probability density function can be obtained by subtracting.  $P(X=a)=0$ unless $a$ is an integer, in which case the sum of the truncated geometric series is $$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1-\frac{1}{2^{a}}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}= 1-\frac{1}{2^a}.$$  If you would like $P(b<X \leq c)$, then add the above in the appropriate range.

Comment: I suspect you meant to write $\lfloor z\rfloor:=\sup(\{n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}|n\leq z\})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by simplifying: $$F_{X}\left(z\right)=\begin{cases}
1-2^{-\lfloor z\rfloor} & \text{if }z\geq1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$